# Error in Linq Expression GroupBy in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, group-by

After migrating the code from .NET Core 2.1 into 3.1 the following Linq is not working . it shows the InvalidOperationException in LinqExpression - GroupByShaperExpression

```
Message=The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: new { 
    DepotNo = (g.DepotNo), 
    DepotName = (g.DepotName)
 }, 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: DepartmentWorkTime
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .Select(dd => new { 
        id = (object)dd.DepotNo + "." + (object)dd.DepartmentID, 
        title = (object)dd.Depot.DepotNo + "." + dd.Department.DepartmentName
     })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I have two model  and another view model

```
Depot Model
public class Depot
    {
        [Key]
        public int DepotNo { get; set; }
        public string DepotName {get;set;}
`    }

public class Department 
    {
        [Key]
        public int DepartmentID{ get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName {get;set;} 
    }

public class DepartmentWorkTime
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DepotNo { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public DepotModel Depot { get; set; }
       public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following record in Depot model  and Department model

```
Depot Model
{1, .AAAA Depot},
{2, BBBB Depot},
{4, CCCC Depot},


Department Model
{1, Retail},
{2, Office},
{3, Field Staff},
{4, Warehouse},


DepartmentWorkTime  List
{1,1,1, Depot Model ,Department Model},
{2,1,2, Depot Model ,Department Model},
{3,1,4, Depot Model ,Department Model},

{4,2,1, Depot Model ,Department Model},
{5,2,2, Depot Model ,Department Model},
{6,2,3, Depot Model ,Department Model},

{7,4,1, Depot Model ,Department Model},
```

I am trying to get the result from linq as

```
[0] = { id = 1, title = "1-AAAA Depot", subs = {System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType10<string, string>>} }
Subs

[0] { id = "1.1", title = "1.Retail" }  <Anonymous Type>
[1] { id = "1.2", title = "1.Office" }  <Anonymous Type>
[2] { id = "1.4", title = "1.Warehouse" }   <Anonymous Type>

[1] = { id = 2, title = "2-BBBB Depot", subs = {System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType10<string, string>>} }    
Subs
[0] { id = "2.1", title = "2.Retail" }  <Anonymous Type>
[1] { id = "2.2", title = "2.Office" }  <Anonymous Type>
[2] { id = "2.3", title = "2.Field Staff" } <Anonymous Type>



[2] ={ id = 3, title = "4-CCCC Depot", subs = {System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType10<string, string>>} }

Subs
[0] { id = "4.1", title = "4.Retail" }  <Anonymous Type>
```

For that purpose I have written the linq as given below , it is working in .Net Core 2.1 but not 3.1

```
**public JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap()
        {
            dynamic mappingList = new List<DepotMapModel>();
            mappingList = _unitOfWork.Department.GetDepotWithDepartment();         
            return Json(mappingList);

        }

 
    public class DepartmentMapModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    public class DepotMapModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<DepartmentMapModel> subs { get; set; }
    }
 
 public dynamic GetDepotWithDepartment()
        {
            var list = goContext.goDepartmentWorkTime.
                GroupBy(d => new { d.DepotNo, d.Depot.DepotName })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                id = g.Key.DepotNo,
                title = g.Key.DepotName,
                subs = g.Select(dd => new
                {
                    id = dd.DepotNo + "." + dd.DepartmentID,
                    title = dd.Depot.DepotNo + "." + dd.Department.DepartmentName
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
            
            return list;
        }**
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is literally swamped with this GroupBy error. This shape is not supported. Please take a look at other questions.

Answer (score 0):

in the new EF core version, it only allows the last Select() call to be evaluated on the client.

You can get all the data by calling goDepartmentWorkTime, so you do not need to use groupby, check this:

```
var list = (from d in _context.goDepartmentWorkTime                      
                     select new
                     {
                         id = d.DepotNo,
                         title = d.Depot.DepotName,
                         subs =  new
                                {
                                    id = d.DepotNo + "." + d.DepartmentID,
                                    title = d.Depot.DepotNo + "." + d.Department.DepartmentName
                                }
                     }).ToList();
```

Result:

[image]